# how to locate module for python on mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, module, python-requests

Naveens-MacBook-Pro:VOIP naveenbaskaran$ python voip1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voip1.py", line 8, in 
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
Naveens-MacBook-Pro:VOIP naveenbaskaran$ python3 voip1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voip1.py", line 8, in 
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Naveens-MacBook-Pro:VOIP naveenbaskaran$ python voip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voip.py", line 8, in 
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
Naveens-MacBook-Pro:VOIP naveenbaskaran$ python3 voip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voip.py", line 8, in 
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Naveens-MacBook-Pro:VOIP naveenbaskaran$ pip2 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Naveens-MacBook-Pro:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pip, you can open the terminal and enter `pip show <module name>`, and under location, you should see where the module is located.